# Bullet points in Mindmap annotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, annotations, easylist

I want to have bullet points in front of the two items in the blue annotation. I tried it with easy list,  but it didn't work. Is there a way to use bullet points in annotations?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic,
     every node/.style=concept, concept color=lime!80, level 1/.append   style={level distance=5cm, sibling angle=120}, level 2/.append style={level distance=3 cm, sibling angle=60}, every annotation/.style={concept color=blue!20, text width={}, align=left}]

    \node{Lehramt}
child{node{Pädagogik}
        child{node{Steop}}
        child{node{Erziehen und Beraten}}
        child{node{Lehren und Lernen}}
        child{node{Schul\-architek\-tur}}
}
child{node{Sport}
    child{node{Physio\-logie}}
    child{node{Anatomie}}
    child{node{Inklusives}}
}
child[level distance=6cm]{node{Französisch}
    child{node{Sprach\-kurs}}
    child{node (n2) {Fach\-didaktik}}
    child{node{Sprach\-wissen\-schaft}} 
    child{node{Landes\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Medien\-wissen\-schaft}}
    child{node{Literatur\-wissen\-schaft}}
}
    ;
    \node [annotation, right] at (n2.east) {Französich unterrichten lernen \\ Wie gestaltet man Unterricht?} 
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

With easy list I tried it like that

```
    \node [annotation, right] at (n2.east) {\begin{easylist}[itemize]
    & Französisch unterrichten lernen
    & Wie gestaltet man Unterricht?
    \end{easylist}}
```

Thank you :)

[image: Mindmap]

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding as a text your bullet via (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm). Another suggestion could be to use a `\minipage` environment at your annotiation.

Comment: @Matsmath Which one from the bullet hardcodes should I use? Sry I'm still a beginner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with

```
    \node [annotation, right] at (n2.east) {$\bullet$ Französich unterrichten lernen \\
    $\bullet$ Wie gestaltet man Unterricht?};
```

[image]

wit \textbullet instead of $\bullet$ for the first bullet point
[image: mindmap]

Comment: Nice, this is what I have suggested. However, I am not entirely sure if the bullet is correctly centered with the text right next to it. You can try using `\textbullet` (without using the math-markup $ signs).

Comment: @Matsmath the first bullet point is with \textbullet , it is more centered, but it is very small...  I don't know if i's possible to put a picture in an comment.... It doesn't bothers me too much, that the bullet points with math-markup $ signs is not correctly centered, and I like the big bullet points more... I think I'll leave it like that. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: @Matsmath I can't. It says I have to wait two days until I can accept my own answer